# Implementing a heirarchial tree

Tags: algorithm

Any idea how I can get started on building a heirachial tree? This tree is passed an employeeID and a managerID. The links between nodes imply a relationship- a node higher up in the tree is a manager of nodes lower down. However, we want operations on the tree to be efficient e.g. search should be O(lg n). Any ideas? Is this even possible?

**EDIT:**

I am in genuine need of help. Might I inquire why this question is being closed?

Comment: I think you will need to explain more about what you want. It's not clear to me, at least.

Comment: You should probably elaborate on the statement _"we want operations on the tree to be efficient"_

Answer (score 2):

I would have a tree to manage the relationships, while maintaining a map to keep track of the nodes themselves.

note that I didn't implement the hire, fire, or promote methods. They're pretty simple and are a little beyond the scope of the basic structure (they're self explanatory from the code below. If they don't jump out at you right away, then you need to study how it works a little more for your own sake!)

```
class OrgChart {

    // Assume these are properly constructed, etc...
    static class Employee {
        String name;
        EmployeeID id;
        Employee manager;
        Set<Employee> underlings;
    }

    static class EmployeeID {
        // what is the id? id number? division  + badge number?
        // doesn't matter, as long as it has hashCode() and equals()
    }

    Map<EmployeeID, Employee> employeesById = new HashMap...

    Employee ceo = new CEO.getTheCEO();

    public Employee getManagerfor(EmployeeID id) {
        Employee dilbert = employeesById.get(id);
        return dilbert.manager;
    }

    public Set<Employees> getEmployeesUnder(EmployeeID phbid) {
        Employee phb = employeesbyId.get(phbid);
        return phb.underlings;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, glow, but the IDs do not indicate the rank of the employee. id #1 might be the janitor and #200 might be the ceo. im currently looking at a nested b-tree approach. what do you think?

Comment: Umm, in my example ID doesn't represent the rank. I just have an internal mapping of ID to the employee record. As far as your b-tree approach, I'd have to see what you mean by that. Are you talking about for your employee-to-manager relationship? Because I thought b-tree had a limited number of children per node, which is not something you'd want to impose. (You might have a volunteer manager who has hundreds of 'employees' under him on the org chart.)

Answer (score 0):

you create an object which contains 2 properties:

- Manager (hierarchical up)
- Employees (hierarchical down) --> is a collection

thats it

you could even realize it without the relation to the manager if you always start at the "big boss" and do a top down search

Comment: no problem: you set the manager property of the "middle manager" to the "top manager" and add the "middle manager" to the employee collection of the "top manager"

Comment: makes sense. but then how do we do a search by ID? we can't do a O(lg n) search. we can only do a BFS or DFS.

Comment: if you want really efficient search you can implement it as a B tree. but the basic structure stays same

Comment: not exactly a b tree as you cant use the balancing. (you cant just change employees cause its not balanced).

Answer (score 0):

Well, with any tree, I feel that you should treat the nodes as equal, in that any node can contain subnodes (including the subnodes).  With that in mind, for most trees I tend to take a parent -> child approach, for example:

User Table:

```
ID    ParentID    Name
1      0          Joe
2      0          Sally
3      2          Jim
```

Now, in this table, Joe & Sally are root level, while Jim is a child (employee in this case) of Sally.  This can continue, with other users being children of users that are, even themselves, children of others and so on....

The benefit of this approach is that you make all users equal in the eyes of the tree control. You won't need customized object collections for each specific level, or complex logic for determining user types and injecting them in to the right node. If you have to sort them manually, all you need is a simple recursive function to check the parents for children based on their ID (with 0 as root in this example).

As for the actual implementation, at least in ASP.NET, I would suggest looking in to the use of a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx), [HierarchicalDataSourceControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.hierarchicaldatasourcecontrol.aspx), and a [HierarchicalDataSourceView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.hierarchicaldatasourceview.aspx). Together these three objects let you implement data trees relatively quickly, and the patterns used are pretty generic, so you can adapt it to use future data objects.